# IE7 is rendering my page wrong

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have this [page](http://posnation.com/shop_pos/pos_hardware) which renders great in all the browsers that I have tested except for IE7

here is my relevant HTML

```
<div class="col col-left">
    .....
    .....
</div>

<div class="col col-right">
    .....
    .....
</div>

<div class="col col-middle">
    .....
    .....
</div>
```

and the CSS...

```
.col-left {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.col-left, .col-right {
    width: 186px;
}
.col-right {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.col-middle {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 7px;
    width: 559px;
}
```

The problem that in IE7 the middle div .col-middle is falling to the bottom and not in the middle like it is in ie8 and firfox and chrome. ANy ideas why IE7 is displaying it off

Comment: Differences in box model calculations. IE has always had horrible bugs in how it calculates the total height/width of a box. Try reducing the size of the .col-middle div to see if shaving 10px or something makes it pop back into place in IE7. If it does, then you've got a box model bug: http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2007/09/12/ie-and-the-css-box-model-wronger-than-wrong/

Answer (score 2):

you can check for valid HTML at the [W3C site](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)

Answer (score 2):

Try structuring your html like this:

```
<div class="col col-left">
    .....
    .....
</div>

<div class="col col-middle">
    .....
    .....
</div>

<div class="col col-right">
    .....
    .....
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

With css like this:

```
.col-left {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.col-left, .col-right {
    width: 186px;
}

.col-right {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.col-middle {
    margin-left: 7px;
    width: 559px;
}

.col {
    float: left;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Floating has always been tricky in IE7.  Just giving all of the columns you want to be on the same row `float: left` allows you to keep them in the same order in your markup.  Also, adding the empty div with the clear class stops the float rule from propagating to other, unintended elements (which is likely the cause of the problem you're seeing).

So, as a general rule, always add an empty div with a clear:both as the LAST sibling of any floated elements.  Also, try sticking to floating in one direction.  Mixing float: lefts/rights as siblings is likely to cause weird/inconsistent rendering across browsers.

Comment: Why did you add those IDs? Totally unnecessary.

Comment: Just to illustrate which were left/middle/right.  There was no functional reason for them.  They're removed now.  If you downvoted me for this (its cool), please point out what is still wrong with my answer or give me back my zero.

Comment: -1 removed, you shouldn't post extra markup if it's not needed (their place is illustrated perfectly well with the classnames `col-right` etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a float, you cancel your `display: inline` Floated elemenets have `display: block`. That might be part of it.

As all the elements have fixed width, you might try having them in order, left, middle , right, and giving them all `float: left`

Comment: Not accurate, float has a display of it's own, it's not quite block.

Comment: Are you sure? because Webkit Browsers, Firefox and Opera all assign display: block to a floated element.

And the W3C wiki (http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/float) says "The element generates a block box that is floated"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the DOCTYPE at the top of your page!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your `div` columns in another `div` wide enough to contain the columns, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/F8VVW/1/.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="col col-left">
        .....
        .....
    </div>

    <div class="col col-right">
        .....
        .....
    </div>

    <div class="col col-middle">
        .....
        .....
    </div>
</div>
```

...

```
.col-left {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.col-left, .col-right {
    width: 186px;
}
.col-right {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.col-middle {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 7px;
    width: 559px;
}

.wrapper { width: 1000px; }
```